# Requested action aborted: Access violation at address 005F6DB2 in module '***.exe'. Read of address 00000000

Tags: tcp, ftp, jmeter, reset

I am using Apache Jmeter to send FTP load on a Server. After setting up the FTP request on specific IP and port, I get this error:

`Requested action aborted: Access violation at address 005F6DB2 in module '***.exe'. Read of address 00000000`

I know that I have all the access and I don't know why a module can block me, although I know that software (***.exe) is not blocking my ports. What is the problem?
Here is the attached Wireshark screenshot from the server when sending the clients request, the red line is the problem and it occurs in different places each time I run the test.

[image: here]

Comment: "Access violation at address..." is Windows exception, and it's about MEMORY (application tries to access an invalid address in memory), has nothing to do with network. I'm not clear from your description which application gives you this exception, but 1 - that application clearly has a bug (this exception should never happen in well written application), and second, your usage of that application somehow triggers that bug. So you could review whatever you are doing vs. prescribed usage of that application.

Comment: Oh, and another option: if your computer is infected with some sort of virus, "Access violation" can start happening to any exes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be related to JMeter

Try uploading file(s) using "normal" FTP client like [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) or [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/download.php).

1. If the problem persists:

   - try identifying its cause using [Windows Event Viewer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749408(v=ws.11).aspx)
   - try to trace system calls using i.e. [WinDbg](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/download-windbg)
   - or just raise an issue on your application (FTP component)
2. If the problem does not occur on "real" FTP clients:

   - double check that your FTP Request sampler configuration is correct, see [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter) guide for details.
   - try uploading the file to the other, i.e. public FTP server to see if it works
   - try implementing file upload purely in Groovy using [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler). See [FTPClientExample.java](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java) for the code you could re-use. Make sure you have the following line in your script:

     ```
     ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true))
     ```